# How long will a wheel of cheese keep?

Tags: cheese, food-preservation

I am planning to go up to Vermont this spring to visit Jasper Hill Farms and Shelburne Farms to buy a wheel of cheese each from their cheddar houses. Once I cut into the wheel, how long before it goes bad?

Comment: Hello Drisheen, it makes no sense for our site to have one question for the expected shelf life of each possible food item in the world. Please refer to our general resource on such matters (the duplicate target question). If it is too generic for your needs, StillTasty.com offers a very good database for shelf lives.

Comment: I'd ask the cheese maker themselves.

Comment: @rumtscho So, it is ok to ask how long roux will keep (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21146/how-long-will-roux-keep) and scallops (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/how-long-will-fresh-scallops-keep-in-the-refrigerator?rq=1) but not cheese?

Comment: What do you mean by "OK"? All three are on topic, but they are all a duplicate of a more general question. Your cheese one was asked after the duplicate target existed, the other two before that. I now closed the earlier ones too.